# Difference between TIFF files exported by ArcGIS and GDAL

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I am doing some testing were I have created a radom raster in ArcGIS in TIFF format. It created a .tif and a .tfw file (where it stores the coordinates). Then I imported this TIFF file into GDAL, did some operations as a numpy array with it and then exported again the array to TIFF file with GDAL. The result is a .tif file, but no .tfw file. However, this resulting TIFF file has all the right coordinates and CRS defined in ArcGIS. How come the one exported from GDAL doesn't need a .tfw file and the one exported from ArcGIS does? Are they different types?

Comment: GeoTIFF stores all the same information than .tfw and quite a lot more inside the tiff file. You can make GDAL to create .tfw with creation option `-co TFW=YES`. ArcGIS can write GeoTIFFs as well. Perhaps you could delete the .tfw and GDAL could still get the georeferencing. Have you tried?

Comment: @user30184 You should have posted your comments as answer.

Comment: So a TIFF+TFW is different than a GeoTIFF that has the information embedded in it? I have only been able to write TIFF+TFW with ArcGIS, not GeoTIFF. In this case I am using Python to carry out this process.